# Is this simple trig Limit true?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

While learing about light specifically fringe seperation calculation, the formula $d\sin \theta = m\lambda$.

While doing this my tutor told me for really small angles $\sin \theta $ the values become very close to $\tan \theta$.

He proved this through a geometric method by reducing the length of the opposite side.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin x = \tan x$

Is this true and is there any other methods of proving this?

P.S. Sorry for the quailty of the question before:<

Comment: That is neither true nor false. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: More likely you learnt that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \sin x = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \tan x$ which is explained by the simple fact that $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

Comment: Not only is it not true, it really makes no sense. Because $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)$ is a _number_ (if the limit exists,  which of course it does), not a function of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that you want to make is that $\operatorname{sin}(x) - \operatorname{tan}(x) = O(x^2)$ at $0$, which means that their difference goes to zero as fast as a quadratic function. You can see that by doing a Taylor expansion and taking the appropriate limits, I won't get too technical on you here as you apparently first need to learn a bit more about the notion of a limit itself; I assume that you will also learn that sooner or later. Greetings,

Intergalakti

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Could you explain to me what the "o" means? Is it like f(x)?

Comment: I made a small error, it must be a big "O". If $f$ and $g$ are functions, we say that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, i.e. f is of order g for x going to $0$, if the ratio $|f(x)/g(x)|$ goes to a constant $C$ if x goes to $0$, i.e. f and g are roughly of the same order of magnitude, or behave similarly when going to zero. The symbol $O$ (or $o$, which means something different, my bad) is called Landau symbol. So what your tutor told you is that sine and tangens behave similarly for very small numbers, and their difference is only of order $x^2$, which is usually negligible.

Answer (score 0):

no it's not. $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin x=\sin0=0$